# SBT getting the classpath mixed up

Tags: sbt

I have a multi module project.
I have three sub projects. They have dependencies that pull in Guava 19.
I explicitly added Guava 21 as a dependency.

When I view the dependency graph I can see that Guava 19 was evicted by 21.

When I try to compile on the commandline it does not find method in Guava 21 because the classpath has 19 before 21.

Is this a bug ?

Comment: Did you add the dependency to all subprojects? Which subprojects generate the compile error? It needs to be added as a direct dependency to each subproject that uses it.

Comment: It is added to every subproject that needs it. Only one project uses the new collectors methods in Guava 21 - that is the methods that are not found.